# Simple Module in Craft CMS 3

Tags: craft3, php, modules

How do I create a simple module for one website in Craft?. I don't have much experience in Craft CMS.  I have tried from 3 days but I cannot get an answer. I'm following all the tutorials that I can find, but none I feel are clear. Any recommendations on the simplest of examples, even if it's just outputting a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the manual: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html

This blog post covers module development in more detail:
https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module

It includes a link to generate a scaffold module, which should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: thanks alot. that help me so much @Richard

Answer (score 1):

I recently reviewed a fellow developer's module and posted [a recording of the review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWChfY5360E) online. It's not necessarily building a module from scratch, but I did very briefly cover the different parts of a simple module Class, and also specifically how to access and save FreeForm submissions and Craft entries, so hopefully it could be of some help. The only part I did not really cover in the video was hooking it all up in the `composer.json` and `config/app.php` files, but that should be fairly explanatory from [the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html).

Comment: but how to run this module. i am totally new in craft @jalen